# registering a custom error handler on routes prefixed with something specific

Tags: python, flask

My app has an application factory pattern, which looks as follows:

```
def create_app(environment):
  # ...

  from root import root
  from charts import user_charts, download_charts
  app.register_blueprint(root)
  app.register_blueprint(user_charts, url_prefix='/charts/user')
  app.register_blueprint(download_charts, url_prefix='/charts/downloads')

  return app
```

Root has an errorhandler that is special for the app, as it is the root blueprint

```
@root.app_errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
  return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

This is good for if they are trying to visit a page which doesn't exist at all. However, on the urls prefixed with `/chart`, the front end makes a request to the back end for the json object. I want to have a uniform handler on all of those routes, in a less cumbersome way than explicitly registering it on every blueprint, as there are around 10. I don't want to do that. Instead, I want something like this:

```
@(all routes prefixed with '/chart').errorhandler(404)
def chart_not_found(e):
  return jsonify({
    'error': e,
    'message': e.get_description()
  })
```

However, the problem is that there are MANY blueprints prefixed with '/charts'.

Is there a way to register the same error handler across multiple urls which share a prefix, rather than repeating it on every blueprint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply register it at init time:

```
def chart_not_found(e):
  return jsonify({
    'error': e,
    'message': e.get_description()
  })

def create_app(environment):
  # ...

  from root import root
  from charts import user_charts, download_charts

  user_charts.error_handler(404)(chart_not_found)
  download_charts.error_handler(404)(chart_not_found)
  # ... snip remaining ...
```

You can even make a module-level variable that lists all the chart blueprints and then use `for`:

```
# charts/__init__.py
chart_handlers = (('/charts/user', user_charts),
                  ('/charts/downloads', download_charts))

# Then in your init setup
from charts import chart_handlers

for prefix, chart_handler in chart_handlers:
    chart_handler.error_handler(404)(chart_not_found)
    app.register_blueprint(chart_handler, prefix)
```

Comment: Also, it may be worth looking at [`Flask-HipPocket`](https://github.com/svieira/Flask-HipPocket) for some other patterns that are helpful with larger applications (disclaimer, I am the author).